# Is there a way to step through a Rails app in a debugger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

Is there a way to step through a Rails app in a debugger as it handles a request?

Comment: Yes. Check out the [Rails guide on debugging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) - particularly the section about ruby-debug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use pry and [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger). Visit http://pryrepl.org/ for more info.

Comment: Note that if you're using an application server that runs independent of the terminal (Passenger, Unicorn, etc) you can use something like https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote to connect a terminal to that process and debug.

Comment: This is still a top search result in 2019.  pry-debugger appears to be only a command line tool for Ruby scripts, not Rails apps. The byebug gem -- courtesy of Jimmy Cuadra's docs link -- seems to be the simplest, if crudest, approach to doing what the op wants.  Personally I'd like Rubymine to do step-through as well as PHPStorm does, but I haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Assuming you've started rails with:

```
rails s --debugger
```

and got a line in your code:

```
debugger
```

then, when you hit that breakpoint, just press:

```
Enter
```

to step through code line-by-line. You will also see Ruby code being executed en route as your app is being parsed. Not sure how you switch that off.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. All you have to do is install Netbeans 6.9. It has a fastdebugger inbuilt in it. You should start the server in Debug mode. You can then set breakpoints in your code and step and inspect line by line.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Rubymine debugger. Rubymine is a paid Rails IDE.